# how to call a command from a bash script in Linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command, rm

I am trying to call a command from a script (defined as functions inside .bashrc) as following

the first function hooks the rm command by deleting any file except a file named "forensicfile1"

```
#hooking rm command
function rm(){
if [[ $1 = "forensicfile1" ]]; then
echo "$1 file is deleted by user ">forensicaudit
else 
rm $1
fi
}
```

the second hooking function is trying to hook the ls command by listing all files except the forensicfile1

```
#hooking ls command
function ls(){
if [[ $PWD = "/home/waleed/forensicdata" ]]
then
alias myls='ls "/home/waleed/forensicdata" -1 "forensicfile1" '
myls
else 
ls $PWD 
fi
}
```

however the following lines are not working

```
rm $1 // within the first function

alias myls='ls "/home/waleed/forensicdata" -1 "forensicfile1" '
myls
ls $PWD
```

can anyone help?

Comment: When you call `rm` from within the function `rm`… well, the function calls itself `:)` and you get an infinite loop. Use `command rm "$1"` instead. Aliases are tricky in this case; why do you want to use an alias anyway? And you're missing lots of quotes.

Comment: When you say, _the following lines are not working_, what error are you facing? terminal stuck at same point or repeating the same command continuously? If yes, then it's the mistake as pointed out in above comment (function calling itself). If you are facing some other issue, clarify in question, _what_ is not working.

Comment: Why are you trying this? Hide the file for other users? Try `chmod`.

Comment: thank you very much. now all problems are solved I just add command before every command as you suggest